# Number of Connected Nodes in a dendrogram

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

Just started working with the tidygraph and ggraph packages recently and have a relatively simple problem, though, oddly, cannot seem to find an easy solution.  Within a network, how many nodes are connected down from a single parent?  Would seem to be a fairly simple question, but have struggled to arrive at an answer, especially when there are multiple "parent/child" relationships that need to be unfolded.

```
# reproducible example -----------------

library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidyverse)

parent_child <- tribble(
  ~parent, ~child,
        "a", "b",
        "b", "c",
        "b", "d",
        "d", "e",
        "d", "f",
        "d", "g",
        "g", "z"
)

# converted to a dendrogram ------------

parent_child %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = "dendrogram") +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),
                 vjust = -1,
                 hjust = -1) +
  geom_edge_elbow()
```

This result is a network
[image]

What I want to know; how many nodes are connected to point "b" when moving out/down (ignoring node "a")? The answer I would expect is 6, or, including "b", then 7.

I am running this over a network of about 5000 individuals, so filtering individual nodes by name is not a great solution.  No one else in my office is familiar with network analyses, so have been kind of left on my own to figure this out.  Really hope someone has an insight! In the mean time will keep reviewing the problem and possible solutions :) Thank y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `ego_size()` from the `igraph` package.  It needs an `order` parameter but you could use the edge count to capture the maximum possible order of the neighborhood.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(parent_child)

ego_size(g, order = ecount(g), nodes = "b", mode = "out", mindist = 1)

[1] 6
```

For multiple nodes, just pass a vector of the nodes of interest:

```
ego_size(g, order = ecount(g), nodes = c("b", "d", "g"), mode = "out", mindist = 1)

[1] 6 4 1
```

Comment: I think this resolves the problem I was having very well; when I was reviewing the tidygraph and igraph packages, did not understand what ego_size or ego functions meant.  Will experiment with this solution, but I think this is the solution.  Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: Rather than using the ecount() function, decided on using the graph_size or graph_order function to specify the extent of the network (both accomplish much the same thing as ecount or vcount).  Either way, your solution worked perfectly :)

Comment: Fair enough - for the record `tidygraph::graph_size()` is a wrapper for `igraph::gsize()` which is also what `ecount()` is an alias of so these are the same function.